# Creating a flag for first and last in SAS

Tags: if-statement, sas

I want to be able to create a flag, here called timeflag, that is set to 1 for every first and last entry of a certain Session, designated by `logflag`. What I have is the following but this gives me `null` data points:

```
data OUT.TENMAY_TIMEFLAG;
   set IN.TENMAY_LOGFLAG;
   if first.logflag then timeflag = 1;
   if last.logflag then timeflag = 1;
run;
```

What is it about the `first.` and `last.` functions that I am not understanding here or is it that I have 2 if statements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
data OUT.TENMAY_TIMEFLAG;
   set IN.TENMAY_LOGFLAG;
   by logflag;
   if first.logflag then timeflag = 1;
   if last.logflag then timeflag = 1;
run;
```

P.S. in this case the dataset `IN.TENMAY_LOGFLAG` should be sorted by `logflag`.

Answer (score 2):

To have SAS create FIRST. and LAST. automatic variables you need to use a BY statement.  If you want the new variable to be coded 1/0 then no need for the IF statement, just assign the automatic variable to a new permanent variable. To make one variable that is 1 for the first and the last then just use an `OR`.

```
data want;
  set have;
  by logflag ;
  timeflag = first.logflag or last.logflag ;
run;
```